# Error while Clicking on Build APK using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

After **Clean Project**, clicking **Rebuild Project**, working correctly without any single error/warning and even when i run using my phone as emulator, running properly

But When I click on **Build APK**, it shown following error, stucked since last three days but could not getting out of it.

Showing:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
>   Job failed, see logs for details

[image: Error Screen Shot]

build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'veri.solo.appoo'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 6
        versionName '6.4'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/'] } }
/*
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }*/
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/FDxSDKProAndroid.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: is question not so clear or what? still not receiving any answer... waiting for solution

Comment: Please copy and paste the log instead of image. Then paste your app build.gradle. This problem is related with proguard.

Comment: added.. review now please

Comment: First, remove `compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')` then add compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0'

Comment: everything else is set, but now getting:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStripIcs$SingleLineAllCapsTransform.class

Comment: You can safely remove `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'` because appCompat-v7 already include it. The error probably because of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134900/discussion-between-teerath-kumar-and---).

Comment: Don't use the whole google play service with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`. Only use the library that you need. Check https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup. After that, you can remove `multidex` in your build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue finally.
I removed the physical file from directory **app > support-v13.jar** and added **android-support-v13** in **build-gradle dependancy** and just **clean** and **rebuild project**.
Now its set.

Thanks to all who supported me.

Answer (score 1):

in your build that gradle, replace your debug config with this

```
debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            jniDebuggable false
            renderscriptDebuggable false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

**minifyEnabled false** you have to do...

Check and let me know